# QB Time Tracking WebService

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, time-tracking

so this is the xml node i am creating for Quickbooks. Sending over duration  (its time kinda thingie)

```
XmlElement duration2 = inputXmlDoc.CreateElement("Duration");
timeTrackingAdd2.AppendChild(duration2);
duration2.InnerText = "PT0H14M0S"
```

as per the format, i am assuming it should convert this into 
0.14 in Quickbooks. But the conversion is different from my assumption

You can see the changed value in the Image Below:
[image: 0.23]
this is the image of the data transferred to QB. It converted the duration to 0.23. What could be the formula here?

Some multiple tries with different values:

```
PT0H1M0S 1 converts to 0.02
PT0H10M0S 10 converts to 0.17
PT0H14M0S 14 converts to 0.23
PT0H30M0S 30 converts to 0.50
```

which approach will help me transfer the duration from my Web Application to Quickbooks converting it into accurate duration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your edited example and [the standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), it converts those inputs to decimal.

```
1 hour converts to 1, thus:
1 minute = 1/60 = 0.0166667 which rounds up to 0.02.
10 minutes = 10/60 = 0.166667 which rounds up to 0.17.
14 minutes = 14/60 = 0.23333 which rounds up to 0.23.
30 minutes = 30/60 = 0.50.
```

Comment: Yeah, i have already tried `PT1H0M0S` and yes the output is `1.00`. But the variance occur in `0M` or `00M` which it shouldn't. As i have values in Decimals like: `0.14`, `0.40`

Comment: Try to do `PT0H01M0S` and tell us if you get the same as the non-zero-padded version.

Comment: just did `PT0H01M0S` converted to `0.02`

Comment: Come to think of it, the result was fine from the start, **1/60 = 0.0166667, which rounds up to 0.02**.

Comment: yeah, So you are proposing that i should multiply the exact value `0.14` with `60` - `e.g:0.14x60=840` ? that it shows `0.14` there too.

Comment: I'm suggesting the output value is the decimal representation of that field, right now it's in hours. E.g. 2 hours and 30 minutes = 2.5 (hours), taking that into account you can convert to any unit you want (value * 60 will yield minutes, for example).